# How to get json data from javascript response in Puppeteer:

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, automation, puppeteer

I'm writing a test using Puppeteer and Node which requires me to get an access token from a response after logging in.

Current code:

```
//Click Login Button
    const loginButton = await page.$(".click-button.dark.ng-star-inserted");
    response = await loginButton.click();

    const object = page.on('response', async response =>{
       if(response.url().includes("token")){
          // returns the "access_token" i need
          console.log(await response.json());
       }
    });
```

But when I do this:

```
const object = page.on('response', async response =>{
       if(response.url().includes("token")){
         try {

          return JSON.parse(await response.json());

         } catch (error) {

         }
       }
    });

    console.log(object);
```

I only get a promise. After a lot of research this is as far as I've gotten. How can I return the actual json from the promise and leverage later in my code?

Comment: Try catching this await response.json() in a variable and then return that variable.

Comment: I tried that. It returns a JS Promise instead of the actual JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You need to await the event listener as it is returning promise. So code will be

```
const object = await page.on('response', async response =>{
       if(response.url().includes("token")){
         try {

          return JSON.parse(await response.json());

         } catch (error) {

         }
       }
    });
```